# How to check from application that findMyIphone is on or off?

Tags: ios

From my application I want to check whether find my iphone is on or off. What is the way to achieve this feature.

Comment: Seems impossible. There is no such public API to do so.

Comment: It may help if you explain why you want to know this.

Comment: Application requires this feature. Where we just need to notify user for theft reason and all.

Comment: I don't think Apple would ever make this information available to third party apps through an API -public or private (due to obvious security/privacy reasons).